# Keeping a Selenium Driver alive across multiple Python scripts

Tags: python, selenium

I'm working on a series of tests using Fitnesse. Due to Fitnesse only allowing me to return one value at a time, I have a series of assertion tests e.g. check to see if a particular element exists on the page. Each test in fitnesse runs one after the other, which means my driver instance gets destroyed after each test.

While functional - this approach is becoming less than adequate as such simple checks spend most of their time opening and closing the browser.

I've tried to pickle the driver - but haven't had much success in doing so. I get:

```
TypeError: can't pickle file objects
```

I've also tried running a separate python script endlessly and accessing the driver from there, but any scripts that then include this also get caught in an endless loop.

Comment: I may be totally wrong as I have just 1 week of experience playing around with Fitnesse with Java fixtures a year back, but I remember there are special pages like SuiteSetUp and SuiteTearDown. Will that not work for your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should have something like @BeforeSuite annotation in TestNG.
If it has, you can leverage it to instantiate the driver creation which will be utilized by all tests.

We have successfully implemented it using BaseTestClass which has driver variable, we are setting this driver in @BeforeSuite method and then it is being shared by all the tests.
Although this approach has some challenges with it, like you can not run the tests in parallel because the driver is common.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to organise the tests better and adapt to the practice that each test case has it's own instance. If you have really small & fast cases, i would recommend nesting them.

Otherwise i recommend reading about Singleton pattern which allows us to have one instance of webdriver. You can find some examples on the implementation here, just search for selenium singleton. Good luck!